# Edit power point file in custom web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js, powerpoint

Our company has internal web application based on asp.net mvc, web api and knockout. Users can upload file into this applications which is stored in DB (there special api to work with files in our app). One of supported type are pptx. Right now we investigate ability to edit (mainly text) this file in our application, how can this be achieved?

Is it possible for example load google docs, or office 365 to iframe and edit document and save back to our database, are there any web controls which allows to do it?

It can be paid libraries or services

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Try OpenXml Power Point templates processing](http://www.dotnet-geek.co.uk/index.php/openxml-power-point-templates-processing/)

[Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but we already use Open XML SDK, the problem is that this library allow to process file on backend in C# code, but we look at the library/service which has UI and allows to do this on front end

Comment: **https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/View-and-Edit-PowerPoint-555aabda**        
and **https://powerpoint.codeplex.com/**

may be helpful